# SpringBoot error org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am very new to SpringBoot and I am getting error while trying to implement a JPArepository class.The error I am getting is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:  Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandleradapter' defined in class path resource.

This is my CountryRepository class that extends the JPArepository. So far I have written any code inside the class.

```
package com.example.demo.DAO;
import com.example.demo.Entities.Country;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Long> {    }
```

This is my Country entity class:

```
package com.example.demo.Entities;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Country {   
     
private Long id;    
private String country_name;    
private Date create_date;    
private Date last_update;    
private Set<Division> divisions;    
public Country() {}

}
```

This is the class that runs the SpringBoot application

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {    
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);    
 }
}
```

This is the dependencies form the pom.xml

```
<dependencies>        
    <dependency>            
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>            
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>        
    </dependency>        

    <dependency>            
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>            
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>        
    </dependency>        
    
     <dependency>            
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>           
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>            
        <scope>runtime</scope>        
     </dependency>        
    
     <dependency>            
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>            
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>           
        <optional>true</optional>        
     </dependency>        

     <dependency>           
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>            
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>            
         <scope>test</scope>        
     </dependency>    
</dependencies>
```

I also have this config class

```
package com.example.demo.Config;
import com.example.demo.Entities.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;

@Configurationpublic 
public class RestDataConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {
    @Override    
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {        
         config.exposeIdsFor(Country.class);        
         config.exposeIdsFor(Customer.class);        
         config.exposeIdsFor(Division.class);        
         config.exposeIdsFor(Excursion.class);        
         config.exposeIdsFor(Vacation.class);        
         config.setDefaultPageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);                      
         config.setMaxPageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);   
 }
}
```

I've looked around but haven't found any help that satisfies my application. Everything works up until I add the CountryRepository class.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `JpaRepository` interface expects the first generic parameter to be an Entity. An Entity is an object that can be persisted in a database. Mark your `Country` class with `@Entity` & that should resolve the exception.

Also you should name your field variables following camelCase - java convention. `country_name` should be `countryName`.